# Copy screenshot to clipboard isn't working after update to fedora 31

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland, screenshot

After system-upgrading from Fedora 30 to 31 I am super happy with the new release.

The only thing that stopped working I'm aware of is the possibility to copy a screenshot to the clipboard right away.

I use

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> Screenshot area to clipboard
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>   Screenshot window to clipboard

a lot, and miss it very much though.

Google found nothing on this issue,
and I don't really know how to debug it..

I'm running Gnome on Wayland, no specific configuration.
Checked, overrode and reset shortcuts to default - no changes.

Shortcuts are firing, I can mark an area to copy, but the clipboard stays at it's previous content.

Screenshot to file still works like a charm.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your system? Are you using Gnome or KDE or maybe something else? Have you tried to check keyboard shortcuts? Maybe they were reseted to default after upgrade?

Comment: @mrc02_kr added some more info and description, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem with Fedora 31 (Gnome workstation) after upgrading from Fedora 30. I have a Dell OptiPlex 7050 (i7 processor with Intel HD Graphics 630).

The "solution" is to use the X11 login instead of Wayland. This is far from ideal, because I prefer Wayland's rendering of GTK applications and Firefox (which is clearly much better in Wayland, with the better use of the window title bar).

I noted that other people reported this:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1751646

Further, this bugreport (linked to in the above) goes into the detail:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/789#note_631911

Comment: Welcome @Gilbert, your answer looks good but please edit it by removing unneeded part: *"This is a big problem for me, because I need to copy/paste screenshots a lot to documents."* this state does not add anything useful to your answer